# Google actions Digital Transaction API skus:batchGet return 403

Tags: google-api, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

Following Google documentation https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/digital/dev-guide-digital-non-consumables#2b

I try to implement digital Transactions in a test AoG project.
I have already:

- link my AoG with an empty Android App and create an InApp product.
- activate Digital Purchase Api for the project
- activate Actions API on google cloud console

I try to retrieve Play store inventory with following API:
[https://actions.googleapis.com/v3/packages/{packageName}/skus:batchGet](https://actions.googleapis.com/v3/packages/%7BpackageName%7D/skus:batchGet)

The API call failed with status code 403, The caller does not have permission

The service account used to generate the access token is owner of the AoG project, I should not have this kind of error.

One know how to find more informations about this 403 error ?

Is there something to do during the linking of the AoG project with the android App ?

Comment: Are you doing the full authentication flow? Would it work better if you used the [digital goods plugin](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-digital-goods-plugin-nodejs)? It shows [how to implement getting SKUs](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-digital-goods-plugin-nodejs/blob/master/src/digital-goods-service-api.ts#L39).

Comment: Finaly found the bug. Digital Purchase wasn' working on French project... 
Adding another language fix the issue...
https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-digital-goods-nodejs/issues/2